# Check if bool is defined in mixed C/C++

Tags: c++, c

So I'm having issues with some code that I've inherited.  This code was building fine in a C-only environment, but now I need to use C++ to call this code.  The header `problem.h` contains:

```
#ifndef _BOOL
typedef unsigned char bool;
static const bool False = 0;
static const bool True = 1;
#endif

struct astruct
{
  bool myvar;
  /* and a bunch more */
}
```

When I compile it as C++ code, I get `error C2632: 'char' followed by 'bool' is illegal`

I get the same error if I wrap the `#include "problem.h"` in `extern "C" { ... }` (which I don't understand, because there should be no keyword `bool` when compiling as C?)

I tried removing the block from `#ifndef _BOOL` to `#endif`, and compiling as C++, and I get errors:

`error C2061: C requires that a struct or union has at least one member`
`error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'bool'`

I just don't understand how the C++ compiler is complaining about a redefinition of `bool`, yet when I remove the redefinition and try to just use `bool` to define variables, it doesn't find anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that `extern "C"` doesn't mean "compile as C". It means "compile with C linkage". The code inside is still C++, you just aren't allowed to define anything that can't be linked as C.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because `bool` is a basic type in C++ (but not in C), and can't be redefined.

You can surround your code with

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef unsigned char bool;
static const bool False = 0;
static const bool True = 1;
#endif
```

Comment: But that code is also incompatible with C99's `stdbool.h`, beware!

Comment: It's still complaining about `char followed by bool is illegal`, so that means it's not reading the `_cplusplus` define?

Comment: @prelic it's two underscores before `cplusplus`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use C99's `bool`:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#include <stdbool.h>
#endif

bool myBoolean; // bool is declared as either C99's _Bool, or C++'s bool data type.
```

Why should you use this?

For compatibility with other C99 code. `_Bool` is commonly used in C99 Code, and is very useful. It also grants you the ability to have a boolean datatype without the need to typedef a lot of stuff, as behind the scenes, `_Bool` is a datatype defined by the compiler.

Comment: Nothing takes one bit in memory. Did you mean to write byte?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore nope, I meant bit. Look into bit fields, when in a struct, bools are packed in a similar way.

Comment: The standard says nothing of size, other than the size of char. The rest is implementation defined. There can exist standard-compliant compilers that use 1Mb to store a bool.

Comment: But still, the first part of your answer - that you should use `stdbool.h` instead of defining your own bool - is correct.

Comment: @Richard if structs packed `bool`s into individual bits, how does `&someStruct.someBoolMember` work?  Are you saying that `sizeof(bool *) > sizeof(int *)`?  And that `sizeof(bool)` somehow returns 1/8 in a `size_t`.  Other than the `vector<bool>` specialization, and bitfields, `bool`s always take at least one byte.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `__cplusplus` macro:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#ifndef _BOOL
typedef unsigned char bool;
static const bool False = 0;
static const bool True = 1;
#endif
#endif
```

Check out this [link to the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) for further details.

Answer (score -5):

I had this "'char' followed by 'bool' is illegal" problem in VS also. 
The problem for me was I did not end my class declaration with a semi-colon- which I was not expecting to be the issue as this was in the header file and the problem was coming up in the cpp file!
eg:

```
class myClass
{

}; // <-- put the semi colon !!
```

Comment: How is that related to `bool` as the question?

Comment: i was also getting the VS error that was posted in the question of" 'char' followed by 'bool' is illegal" in VS - the fix for me was just to add the semi colon at the end of the class declaration.

Comment: @JustinHirsch Visual Studio is an IDE, not a programming language.