# Using a library written in C with C++

Tags: c++, c, mongoose, server

I'm trying to include mongoose web server, which is written in C, and write the rest of the code in C++.
When compiling I get the error: redeclaration of C++ built-in type 'bool' in the mongoose header file in Code Blocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mongoose.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I enclosed the mongoose header in

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C"{
#endif 
// header content
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

and I'm still getting the same error, at #include winsock2.h

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if bool is defined in mixed C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636120/check-if-bool-is-defined-in-mixed-c-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using C Libraries for C++ Programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066279/using-c-libraries-for-c-programs)

Comment: Declaring C linkage is not a silver bullet, contrary to the claims of one of the linked answers.

Comment: can you change the contents of the mongoose header?

Comment: and can you show us the line that the error is referring to?

Comment: Yes, I can modify the mongoose header. The error occurs at line 214, https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/mongoose.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your only issue, then you could add `#define bool C_INT_BOOL` near your `extern "C"`, then `#undef bool` near the `}`
In your cpp file I would write:

```
extern "C"{
#define bool C_INT_BOOL
#include "mongoose.h"
#undef bool
}
```

This allows the "C" interface to see the int parameter type, but shouldn't interfere with your c++ use of bool.

But I doubt this will be your only issue, in which case you will probaby quickly realise that adding an interface function layer is the safest way to go.

Answer (score 2):

C and C++ are different languages that share a common subset.  You can compile most C *declarations* with a C++ compiler by putting them in a section specifying C linkage, as you show, but that follows from the sublanguage of C declarations being almost entirely within the shared subset of C and C++.

C++ has both more declarational features and more constraints than C does, however.  In particular, the fact that it provides `bool` as a built-in type places a constraint that that identifier cannot be redeclared as a typedef name.  C, on the other hand, has a standard header that defines exactly such a typedef, and it is not so uncommon for people to roll their own, too.  Such typedefs will be rejected by a C++ compiler, C linkage notwithstanding.

If the C project is not already built with a mind toward providing for use by C++ programs, and simply wrapping the header inclusion in a C linkage block does not suffice, then you simply cannot use that library's header as-is.  Your options are either to modify it or to provide an alternative.  You might even need to provide a few wrapper functions, written in C, to serve as an interface with your C++ program.  Details depend on the library you're trying to use.